# How many strings can you make out of a, b and c, if you can use a letter either one or two times, and you can either use all the letters, or two

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here's a pretty hard combinatorics question that I found in a textbook today:
"How many strings can you make out of a, b and c, if you have to use all of the letters or two of them, and you have to use each letter once or twice". The order is important.

I thought about dividing it into cases based on the length of the word. For example for a word of length 2, we get $3^2 - 3$ (The number of words of size 2 made from 3 letters minus the number of words made from only one letter (In this case the second condition doesn't matter)).

For a word of length 3, we get $3^3 - 3$ because of the same reason

For a word of length 4, we get $3^4 - 3 - (4 \times 3 \times 2)$ (The total number of words minus $aaaa, bbbb, cccc$ minus choosing an index, placing a letter in it, and then placing a different letter in the remaining indices (This gives us words such as $abbb, accc, baaa$ and so on))

Edit: I thought about the solution we get for each case except for the case of length 3 (length $k$), which gives us $3^k - 3^{k-1}$ (We got $3^2 - 3^1$ for length 2, and $3^4-3^3$ for the case of length 4, but I can't figure out how to prove this for the case of length 5, and the case of length 6)

But I couldn't figure out how to continue with this. Can you give me a hint and a solution (in a spoiler tag!!!!!)? Thanks!!

Comment: There aren't that many cases to consider...just split according to how many letters you use and how many times you use them.

Comment: @lulu So it's not necessary to split to cases based on length?

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way, as there are many routes to a single length.  But, you certainly could.  I think it's easier to do it the way I said though.

Comment: Okay great! Thanks @lulu

Comment: What does "you have to use each letter once or twice" mean? If it really meant that the maximum length of any admissible string would be $6$. I suppose "in a row" is missing.