# How many strings can you make out of $a$, $b$, and $c$, using all of the letters or two of them, and using each letter once or twice?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

The problem is "How many strings can you make out of a, b and c, if you have to use all of the letters or two of them, and you have to use each letter once or twice". The order is important.

My solution is:

We'll split it into cases:

Case 1: "Using each letter only once, while using all the letters" 
This is equivalent to arranging 3 kids on 3 chairs, so we have $3!$ for this case.

Case 2: "Using each letter only once, while using 2 of the letters" 
There are $3 \choose 2$ $=3$ ways to choose which letters we use, and then we have $2!$ ways to create a word. Overall, we have $3 \times 2 = 6$ for this case.

Case 3: "Using one letter once, using the other letters two times, while using all the letters" 
The length of the word is 5 in this case, so we can choose an index ($5$ options), and then place the single letter in it ($1$ option). Now, we need to calculate the number of words we can make from $b, b, c, c$ which is $3!$. So we have $5 * 3! = 30$.

Case 4: "Using one letter once, using the other letter two times, while using two of the letters" 
We have $3 \choose 2$ ways to choose the letters, and then we have 4 ways to make the word so we have $3 * 4 = 12$

Case 5: "Using two letters once, and the other letter two times, while using all the letters" 
We choose the other letter (3 options), and then we place it ($3! = 6$) options, and then we pick the character for the remaining places (2 options), so we have 6 * 3 * 2 = 36

Case 6: "Using all the letters twice" 
First, we place $a$: $6 \choose 2 = 15$. Now, we place $b$: $4 \choose 2 = 6$, and now we have only one option to place $c$, so we get $6 \times 15 = 90$

Case 7: "Using two letters twice" 
There are $3 \choose 2$ $=3$ ways to choose which letters we use, and then we have $2! * 2!$ ways to create a word, so we have $3 * 4 = 12$

In conclusion: $6 + 6 + 30 + 12 + 36 + 8 + 12 = 110$

Is this solution correct? Thanks!!

Comment: What about $aabbcc$ and such?

Comment: Also I don't understand your computation for case $5$.  If we have $X,Y, Z,Z$ to work with then we choose $Z$ ($3$ choices), place the $Z's$ ($6$ choices), pick the character for the first singleton ($2$), so $3\times 6\times 2$ which does not match your result.  (didn't check the other cases).

Comment: Post edit:  Case $6$ is wrong.  Given $a,a,b,b,c,c$ to work with, we place the $a's$ ($\binom 62=15$ choices) then we place the $b's$ ($\binom 42=6$ choices) so, $90$ cases.  I suggest:  going through your computations carefully.

Comment: Fixed. aaaaaaaaa

Comment: Go through each case carefully.  I only checked two and both were wrong, so I suspect there may be more errors.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.  If you want to rework your proposed solution, it is better to edit the original post. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524619/how-many-strings-can-you-make-out-of-a-b-and-c-if-you-can-use-a-letter-either